# How to save multiple output in recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion, save

Given a matrix A, I have to make all possible combinations of entries of A such that only one number is selected for each row. I have made a recursive program which is running successfully. But I am not able to save the output vector. So, for example in the following matrix A, there will be 27 such combinations, I want to save them in matrix of order 3x27.

```
A = [3 4 0; 2 3 7; 45 7 0]
n = 1; 
X = zeros(3,1); 
comb(n, X, A); 

%function to calculate all combinations. 
function X = comb(n, X, A)
   if (n > 3)
      X
      return 
   end 
   for i = 1:3 
      X(n) = A(n, i); 
      comb(n + 1, X, A); 
   end
end
```

Comment: can you show us (the important part of) your code ? What do you mean by not being able to save ?

Comment: n=1;
X=zeros(3,1);
comb(n, X, A); %function to calculate all combinations.

function X =comb(n,X, A)
if (n>3)
   X  
  return 
end

for i=1:3
    X(n)= A(n,i); 
    comb(n+1,X,A);
end
end

Comment: Some formatting issues with my code are there. But if you just copy paste it in matlab it will run properly.

Comment: Soltius, now the  code is shown. I want to save each output vector X. In this particular case of matrix A there will be 27 output vectors. I want to save then in a matrix of order 3x27.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one of the possible approaches:

To make your variable visible in all contexts, you need to declare a global variable:

```
global OUT;
%rest of the code
```

Then, you just define `OUT` in you main file as empty variable:

```
OUT = [];
```

And in function script, you instruct to append `X` to `OUT` whenever the if-statement is satisfied:

```
if (n > 3)
  OUT = [OUT,X];
  return 
end
```

The resulting code is as follows:

```
global OUT;
OUT = [];
A = [3 4 0; 2 3 7; 45 7 0];
n = 1; 
X = zeros(3,1); 
comb_SO(n, X, A); 
OUT
function X = comb_SO(n, X, A)
global OUT;
   if (n > 3)
      OUT = [OUT,X];
      return 
   end 
   for i = 1:3 
      X(n) = A(n, i); 
      comb_SO(n + 1, X, A); 
   end
end
```

The sought result is in `OUT` variable:

```
 3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 2   2   2   3   3   3   7   7   7   2   2   2   3   3   3   7   7   7   2   2   2   3   3   3   7   7   7
45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0  45   7   0
```

But, MATLAB functionality allows your goal to be achieved without any recursion:

```
A = [3 4 0; 2 3 7; 45 7 0];
OUT = combvec(A(1,:),A(2,:),A(3,:))
```

Or, even without `combvec`, for arbitrary size of A:

```
A = reshape(1:20,4,5);
[n,m] = size(A);
Q = repmat({1:m},n,1);
B = cell(n,1);
[B{:}] = ndgrid(Q{:})
tmp = [];
OUT = [];
for k = 1:n
tmp = [tmp,B{k}(:)];
OUT = [OUT;A(k,tmp(:,k))];
end
```

Hope, that helps